# Python coordinate collision help wanted

Tags: python

I wanted to make that enemies would not be on same coordinates.
I don't want any other advice like advice that would make my code more clean.
Here is that part of the code:

```
class enemy(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def move(self):
        if self.x*tilesize>x:
            self.x-=1
            if self.x < 0:
                self.x += 1
            elif mappi[self.y][self.x] == stone or mappi[self.y][self.x] == wood:
                self.x += 1
        if self.y*tilesize<y:
            self.y+=1
            if self.y > mapheight-1:
                self.y -= 1
            elif mappi[self.y][self.x] == stone or mappi[self.y][self.x] == wood:
                self.y -= 1
        if self.x*tilesize<x:
            self.x+=1
            if self.x > mapwidth-1:
                self.x -= 1
            elif mappi[self.y][self.x] == stone or mappi[self.y][self.x] == wood:
                self.x -= 1
        if self.y*tilesize>y:
            self.y-=1
            if self.y < 0:
                self.y += 1
            elif mappi[self.y][self.x] == stone or mappi[self.y][self.x] == wood:
                self.y += 1

enemies=[enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),
         enemy(random.randint(0,mapwidth-1),random.randint(0,mapheight-1)),]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ahead of time you do

```
from itertools import product
```

then you can replace that ten-line assignment to `enemies` with

```
mapxy = list(product(range(mapwidth),range(mapheight)))
enemies = [enemy(*xy) for xy in random.sample(mapxy, 10)]
```

This uses `random.sample`, which selects a given number of elements (here 10) from a population, without repeats.

The population we are selecting from are map locations, here described by the Cartesian product of `range(mapwidth)` and `range(mapheight)`. Unfortunately, `random.sample` doesn't work with iterables such as the result of `product`, so we must read it into a list.

The 10 selected elements are tuples (x,y). We unpack each tuple `xy` to two arguments to construct an `enemy` with the star in `enemy(*xy)`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for a quick answer! There is one major problem left: when i do "print(enemies)" it just prints: [<__main__.enemy object at 0x0076E1F0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x012C6330>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x012C98B0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x033DABB0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03831AF0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03831B70>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03831D50>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x0383C110>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x0383CE10>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03E75B10>]. I'd like to convert that into string, how is that done?

Comment: @JormaJarppinen: Give your enemy class a `__str__(self)` method which returns the string you want to describe it.

Comment: I'm just a dumbass Python beginner, so would you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @JormaJarppinen: You know how you already have an `__init__` method and a `move` method? Add another one, called `__str__`.  Write `return "Bad guy at " + str(self.x) + ", " + str(self.y)` or whatever else you want.

Comment: And just one more dumb question: how to make that execute?

Comment: How to make what execute? The `__str__` method? Just `print(enemies)`, the same as before. @Jorma

Comment: It still just gives me: [<__main__.enemy object at 0x007DE1F0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00826330>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x008298B0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x033DABD0>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03D91B10>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03D91B90>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03D91D70>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03D9C130>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03D9CE30>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x03E45B50>].

Comment: @Jorma: it seems that `__str__` works when printing enemy objects directly, but for elements of a list, it uses `__repr__` instead—my bad. If you only provide `__repr__` it will also be used for `__str__` by default, so you can do that; [see here](http://ideone.com/L7xF01)